# Rebuild statusbar on the fly with databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, statusbar

Im building a plugin system where each plugin has its own statusbar, containing different regions. So Plugin #1 could have a statusbar with 2 x 200 pixels regions, while Plugin #2 can have just a single 400 pixel region.

Im building this in `WPF/MVVM` and in my viewmodel for the application, the `StatusBar` for the plugin gets loaded when i switch between plugins.

I have a observablecollection of statusbars that i load to:

```
ObservableCollection<StatusBar> StatusBars 
{ 
    get;
    set;
}
```

And then i have a function just retrieves the collection of statusbars for that plugin.

The class that gets loaded looks something like this:

```
public class StatusBar : ObservableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public StatusBarAreaType Type { get; set; }

    string _message;

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return _message;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_message != value)
            {
                _message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that i cant get the XAML to support me loading the collection and showing each `StatusBar` as its own region. A simplified version of how i tried going about this looks something like this:

```
<StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding StatusBars}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource StatusBarTemplate}">
    <StatusBar.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StatusBarTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StatusBar.Resources>
</StatusBar>
```

(I have tried `StatusBarItem` stuff, `ItemsControl` templates, using a grid inside instead etc etc)

How do i achieve my goal of having a `StatusBar` consisting of different regions based on the StatusBar class?

Comment: This looks like a template selector type of problem.  Have you considered using a template selector?

Comment: I was going to add that at a later stage, to be able to change the content of the region based on the type. But since i couldnt get the regions to work i havent gotten that far yet. How would that solve my issue you mean?

Comment: Why are regions not working?

Comment: Well im currently not getting over the first step of just binding the Itemssource to a model and getting it to produce stuff, and Google has not given me any hits where someone is doing any type of binding on a WPF statusbar. So if you know how to do the first step, please share :)

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand here.  StatusBar inherits from ItemsControl so don't you need to be *items* instead of the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to resolve this now, here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyCompany.View.StatusBarControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyCompany.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding StatusBar,Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SimpleTextDataTemplate">
            <StatusBarItem Width="{Binding Width}" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ErrorDataTemplate">
            <StatusBarItem Width="{Binding Width}" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"></TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarDataTemplate">
            <StatusBarItem Width="{Binding Width}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <ProgressBar Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=theStatusBar,Path=Height}" Value="{Binding Message}"></ProgressBar>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StatusBar x:Name="theStatusBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#d0d2d6" Height="30"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding StatusBars}">
            <StatusBar.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <viewModel:StatusBarRegionSelector SimpleTextTemplate="{StaticResource SimpleTextDataTemplate}"
                                                   ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorDataTemplate}"
                                                   ProgressBarTemplate="{StaticResource ProgressBarDataTemplate}" />
            </StatusBar.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind:

```
public class StatusBarRegionSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate SimpleTextTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate ErrorTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate ProgressBarTemplate { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var statusBar = (StatusBar) item;

            if (statusBar != null)
                switch (statusBar.Type)
                {
                    case StatusBarAreaType.SimpleText:
                        return SimpleTextTemplate;
                        break;
                    case StatusBarAreaType.Error:
                        return ErrorTemplate;
                        break;
                    case StatusBarAreaType.ProgressBar:
                        return ProgressBarTemplate;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }

            return SimpleTextTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Only issue left now is to add a seperator between each item, just adding a seperator right now does not work for some reason, it wont show up no matter where i place it.